# Как перенаправить HTTP-запросы на SOCKS5-proxy

Tags: linux, http, docker, socks5

На днях возникла задача по развертыванию docker сервера, но у него нет поддержки socks5. Как перенаправить докер на socks5-proxy?

Comment: Для линуха есть много разных соксифиеров. Может какой-нибудь подойдёт. Ищите. Сам хотел сокс сервер на дебияне запустить, но в поиске пакетов попадались только соксифиеры. Это программы, которые каким-то образом перехватывают трафик и направляют дальше через сокс-сервер, если программа сама не умеет в сокс.

Comment: Спасибо, будем искать дальше.